# IOS centered UIImages in a row

Tags: ios, uiimage, center, uitableview

I have a little problem. I want to display multiple (amount is dynamic) UIImages in a UITableViewCell (in the center).

How can I do that (UIImages are generated programmatically)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            self.imgThings = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
           // imgThings.backgroundColor= [UIColor magentaColor];
            [self.imgThings setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
            self.imgThings.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.imgThings];
        }
  return cell;

}
```

Above is simple example for only one image, u can also set it for multiple image by changing name of image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your snippet. This nearly what I need. But in my example I have multiple images not only one in ONE row. For example this is a row: (UIImage) | (UIImage) | (UIImage) -- (DetailEnclosure) ; Like a table with one row and multiple columns.

Comment: @Bene What if there are more than 3 images?

Comment: @Bene If you are targeting for iOS 6.0 and above, now might be a good time to learn autolayout. You can set rules to have a minimum padding and rule to have all imageView with same height and width respective to the contentView of cell.

Comment: Hi, I sorry but this has to run on IOS 5. But I found a solution by myself. You can put all UIImageViews in a UIView, center the UIView and calculate width and height with the amount of the pictures and the picture dimensions + a calculated space between each picture to fill up the whole cell.